# How to make a link to a visible part of an object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, png

[strange shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OWaj.png)

I would like to make a link only to the visible part of this strange shape. How to achieve this, do I have to export to svg (path) and then somehow nest?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you want that shape to act as a link, but only the pink parts, you can recreate that shape as an [SVG image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg).